# How to use format property of textbox to add fix 0s before textbox in SSRS

Tags: c#-4.0, reporting-services

I have a column name **EmployeeId** in which I have to fix the length of 9 and if the **EmployeeId** is less then 9 so I want to add 0s before the Id. This is possible in c# with the help of PadLeft method, but I don't know how I can achieve this in SSRS.

Forex:

If EmployeeId = 123, so I want to show like 000000123

If EmployeeId = 123456789 then its ok

Please suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Add to expression of the Employee_ID field:

```
=StrDup(9 - len(trim(Fields!Emplyee_ID.Value)),"0") & Fields!Employee_ID.Value
```

**OR**

You can add derived field for Employee_ID in SQL:

```
SELECT REPLICATE('0', 9 - LEN(Employee_ID)) + CAST(Employee_ID AS char) AS Employee_ID_Full
FROM TABLENAME
```